# Unable to read RTF file using Perl on Mac

Tags: perl, file, macos

I'm trying Perl on Mac. 
I have to read an RTF text file. the content of the file is "36" (without double quotes). thats it, just two characters.

Here is the code I have to read it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "verInfo.rtf";

unless(open FILE, $file) {
    # Die with error message
    # if we can't open it.
    die "\nUnable to open $file\n";
}

my $oldversion = <FILE>;

print "conent is $oldversion";

close FILE;
```

Remember all I want is to read the value 36 from file and store it as a integer in $oldversion

But when I read the file and print it, it prints following

```
conent is {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
```

Im not able to read 36.

Comment: The SO community has worked to provide you an answer. Please accept one of these answers by clicking the tick box below the vote count. It will boost your own rep score as well.

Comment: I've never seen a file being opened like that before... too used to `open my $fileHandle, '<', $file or die "Unable to open $file: $!\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reading a text file, you're reading an RTF file. You made the file with TextEdit, right? TextEdit saves things as text/rtf rather than text/plain by default, if you want to save the file as plain text you should use "Format | Make Plain Text" (AKA Shift-Cmd-T) before you save it; then you'll get a simple text file with just your "36" in it.

Comment: Ya thanks for the answer, I created a txt file in Terminal as  vi verInfo.txt   and it worked. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The text is there:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
                                                ^^
```

You have an RTF file. Use [an RTF parser](https://metacpan.org/search?q=rtf)